# command i could use to separate hypothetical proteins from a set of protein?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a big file of 5000 protein sequences in fasta, of these there are hypothetical proteins and function proteins, how can i separate the hypothetical proteins from the putative proteins. so basically hypothetical proteins have the word hypothetical in their heading so i was hoping i could use some how a command to separate them. does any one know a python or linux command to do this? some thing like this

> vir0002 BASYS00002, 605-1000 (Clockwise) MobC Protein
>   MPKPASDGAGSGCHVQAGVTSLPTEYPFDRRKSRMARTQTFTQEQLDKTKQALSELPDLS
>   RNKIAKADFLESLKDQIVLLANTKGYSPAEIKSALAQVNVTVSVKSIADLLNTQGKRQPR
>   KSADKKSNPTQ
>   vir003 yubP, 2257-1421 (CounterClockwise) UPF0380 protein yubP
>   MQFSNSVRGPNMLRADHPLSNEQIASVAPSIFAAEAYESRSERYLYIPTVEVLDALREEG
>   FEPFMASQTRVRNAGKIEHTKHMLRLRHSSSIMDKEADEIILLNSHDGSSSYQMMAGVFR
>   FVCQNGLVIGDRSFDQKIRHSGNDDIKSDVIEGAYEVLDQFKAMSEQKECMKQIKLCADE
>   QEAFATAALSYRYDPQEGPAPVTARQLLSPRRVEDYENDLWTTFNRIQENSIKGGLRGRN
>   KSGRRATTRSVSGIDQDVKLNRALWTLAQELRGHLTTA
>   vir004 BASYS00004, 3593-2535 (CounterClockwise) Nuclease
>   MHELSAEAASQLEALEKELESVQATIESLSDQDSEQSKALDIREDELEDEISKIQKSREG
>   FALEVMPHAGAVISYYYGDLRINRGMVRTADRESVNAVLGEGERLAGGRETESAGRKSNT
>   ISDALRRSLLGHRNLAAQFVTAANPKAAKMLIVCKWISDTRRNWSATPTDLSIGNGYGAR
>   TGCPITDEAGRVREEEFVALGELLIEGLPTEYGDLWDALAALSEAEIDKLLAFAVARSVS
>   LAVEDNVLSKKYVQTLGMKMEDHFVPTVGNYLGRVSKELIIEALKEARKIQSDEDQVTLL
>   AMKKGALAAEAETRLMGTGWVPAEIATKPEELAQEKNSKKKKNSSKPATGKA
>   vir005 yubM, 4624-3506 (CounterClockwise) Uncharacterized protein yubM
>   MSLHVVTLMCVECITIPSALHRHRCPIRAAATAPGLPCRGFYMSNAYNTVVPFNRLRRSE
>   ENVRRTGRASAHYKAGIKKLAASILSTHKQTGQGLLQNLVVHVNGENFDVAAGGRRYDAV
>   SLLIEEGEFQADYPTACLVIDADAVTAASLTENVSREAMHPADELDAFKALTEQGWTIDS
>   IPDSFGVTALVVERRLKVRAAAPALIEEYRLGALTTDQLIALCATDDHDRQLEVWNRLRQ
>   QHWNNDPATLRRAVIKTEVESNDKRVTFIGGVEVYEAAGGEVRRDLFAEDGQGAFLSDSA
>   LLDVLVETKLQEVGEQVRAEGWGWIEVWQQFDHTHTVWATHRRSCMSCQPKQLVSLKHWK
>   RSLRAYRPPLRA
>   vir006 BASYS00006, 5844-5293 (CounterClockwise) Hypothetical Protein PSPTOA
>   MCPKLKAYHWQQGRHSPALNWKITVSAKNTDEQLLAMATKIKESYTPSEIAQLVRLISPT
>   PNTGELSAEEFERVMQVLGSQNNRRPYSSKSVIAARLVLVMGASPSEAAKESGLARQNVS
>   ELMLRIRKRMESLPQGWVKVSEWFPGEVAKQIGHISEALKDHHSAGKPLNELSFTIKLTG
>   PTA

and i would expect to have two files 
one containing

> vir006 BASYS00006, 5844-5293 (CounterClockwise) Hypothetical Protein PSPTOA
>   MCPKLKAYHWQQGRHSPALNWKITVSAKNTDEQLLAMATKIKESYTPSEIAQLVRLISPT
>   PNTGELSAEEFERVMQVLGSQNNRRPYSSKSVIAARLVLVMGASPSEAAKESGLARQNVS
>   ELMLRIRKRMESLPQGWVKVSEWFPGEVAKQIGHISEALKDHHSAGKPLNELSFTIKLTG
>   PTA
>   and the other containing the rest of the protein sequences

Comment: how different proteins are separated in the file?

Comment: some have proper names ie putative names but others are unknown, so they will have the word hypothetical in the header, i want to extract all those with the word hypothetical in the header

Comment: The file structure isn't understandable in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Biopython has a FASTA parser that should be able to do what you want.  Instructions for getting and using it are at http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc11.

At http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/python-bioinformatics-tools/fasta-parser there is a simple Python script for reading a FASTA file and converting it to a dictionary with header lines (beginning with >) as keys. I do not see those in your examples. How are headers in your files distinguished from sequence content?

https://gamma2.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/reading-a-fasta-file-with-python/ provides stepwise instructions for writing the same sort of script as mentioned above.  It would be easy to add filtering for  headers containing "Hypothetical Protein" to either, skip the hashing and just write the header+sequence output to two different files depending on if the header matches or not.

With Ruby, the bioruby classes Bio::Sequence::Common and Bio::FastaFormat have cool functionality. The first is a mixin with a toFasta method for writing Bio::Sequence objects in FASTA format. The second can read FASTA files in as Bio::Sequence objects and has 7 methods related to FASTA headers (definition lines) and 6 for sequences. See  http://bioruby.open-bio.org/rdoc/Bio/Sequence/Common.html and http://bioruby.open-bio.org/rdoc/Bio/FastaFormat.html with example programs for both starting at http://bioruby.open-bio.org/wiki/SampleCodes#How_do_I_write_Sequences_in_Fasta_format.3F.

Answer (score 0):

@Coeur I hope this amy help, Extract sequence without hypothetical protein, If any suggestion kindly reply, u may get some help from these link https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16378/remove-from-multi-fasta-by-sequence-id
https://python.omics.wiki/biopython/examples/read-fasta
https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/remove-delete-sequences-by-id-from-multifasta
or search key word Remove/delete sequences by ID from multifasta on
https://answerbun.com/

```
from Bio import SeqIO
    import re
    import sys
    
    sequences = SeqIO.parse('input.fasta', 'fasta')
    filtered = [seq for seq in sequences if 'hypothetical protein' not in seq.description]

with open('output.fasta', 'wt') as output:
    SeqIO.write(filtered, output, 'fasta')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31836896)

Answer (score 0):

And to extract only hypothetical proteine use this code

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re #regular expression optional
import sys # command-line arguments to passed the script optional

sequences = SeqIO.parse('input.fasta', 'fasta')
filtered1 = [seq for seq in sequences if 'hypothetical protein' in seq.description]

with open('hypothetical.fasta', 'wt') as hypothetical:
    SeqIO.write(filtered1, hypothetical, 'fasta')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an R script that can be used as

```bash
Rscript gethypothetical.R --fasta organism.pep.all.fa.gz
```

Code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("argparse"))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(seqinr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(protr))
parser <- ArgumentParser(description='Retrive Hypothetical/ Uncharacterized Proteins')
parser$add_argument('-f', "--fasta",help="Provide a input as multifasta file", default=NULL,nargs=1)
args <- parser$parse_args()

fastafile<- read.fasta(file = args$fasta, seqtype = "AA",as.string = TRUE)
f <- fastafile[grep('hypothetical|uncharacterized',getAnnot(fastafile))]
f <- f[(sapply(f, protcheck))]
name <- gsub("\\..*","",basename(args$fasta))
write.fasta(getSequence(f), gsub(">","",getAnnot(f)), paste0(name,".fa"))
```